# Does Ubuntu have the equivalent of a registry, especially for desktop GUI items?

Tags: unity, configuration, gconf, ccsm, dconf

I've seen several references to 'Compiz Config' and a 'gnome config' application that seems to not be installed by default.  Where do these config applications store their data?  Is there a registry similar to Windows or are there just some files that I could edit by hand, if I really, really wanted to?

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/187901/92460)  and also `qdbus --literal com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar` and then `qdbus --literal com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar  /com/canonical/AppMenu/Registrar`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 3 most common applications you will hear about when talking about tweaking Gnome/Unity will be [gconf-editor](http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/), [dconf-editor](http://live.gnome.org/dconf/) and [ccsm](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM).

You can find those in the `Software Center` and install them from there.

The 2 first tools will configure different (sometimes not so different, think of it as a path that leads to the same goal) aspects of your Gnome configuration and the last one is important to configure your Unity/Compiz configuration.

`gconf-editor` stores its data in XML files in `/etc/gconf/`

`dconf-editor` uses files called *key files* stored in `/etc/dconf/db/`

`ccsm` stores its data in XML  files in your `~/.gconf/apps/compiz` and `~/.gconf/apps/compizconfig` folders.

Any of these can be read and edited with a plain text editor (`nano`, `gedit`, etc.), but it sure is a lot of work.  Use the appropriate tools to edit those files, and it will make your life much simpler.

Comment: dconf stores its user settings in `~/.config/dconf/user`, a binary file.  gconf stores its user settings in `~/.gconf`.  ccsm, in ubuntu, by default, stores its settings in gconf as well (though it doesn't have to).

Comment: Correct, nothing wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

gconf is a rough equivalent, but it's important to understand that Ubuntu and Windows are very different systems.  gconf is a "registry" for Gnome, which Ubuntu is now moving away from.  It does not control every aspect of the system.  Much of the lower-level information is in flat text files spread throughout /etc and /usr/share/name-of-app.  User-specific information, including Unity config, is often in dotfiles inside your home directory (that is, files beginning with a ".", so that they are not listed by default.  Press Ctrl+H in the file browser to show them).

In summary:

1. gconf is equivalent to the registry for many GUI issues relating to Gnome, but holds little sway over Unity-related things.
2. Many lower level configuration settings are in flat text files in /etc and /usr/share/
3. Much Unity config is in dotfiles in the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DBus interface  `com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar`  that contains the desktop GUI indicator icons and associated ap interfacing details in the Unity environment as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/187521/89468) .