# "Show Desktop" Not in Nautilus Preferences?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, workspaces, desktop-background

Trying to get multiple backgrounds for different workspaces in 11.10, but having some difficulty. Every guide I see says to change the Nautilus setting "Show Desktop" to unchecked, but I don't have that setting at all.
Help?

Answer (score 5):

It is `dconf-editor` under `/org/gnome/desktop/background` as `show-desktop-icons` in GNOME 3.x versions, which is the version of Nautilus in Ubuntu 11.10.

- [What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-and-what-is-its-function)
- [Does Ubuntu have the equivalent of a registry, especially for desktop GUI items?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70450/does-ubuntu-have-the-equivalent-of-a-registry-especially-for-desktop-gui-items)
- [Graphical editor for GSettings/dconf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15262/editor-for-gsettings-dconf)